# Training a classifer multiple times in order to get average in Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

Every time I train my classifier I get different values for the false positive rate and false negative rate. So what I want to do is to train the classifier 100 times so I can get the averages of the false positive rates and false negative rates.

```
print('\nExecuting Logistic Regression')
    all_fpr = []
    all_tpr = []
    all_roc_auc = []
    all_acc = []
    all_recall = []
    for i in range(0, 100):
        lr_values = lrRocAucTest.execute(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
        all_fpr.append(lr_values['fpr'])
        all_tpr.append(lr_values['tpr'])
        all_roc_auc.append(lr_values['roc_auc'])
        all_acc.append(lr_values['accuracy'])
        all_recall.append(lr_values['recall'])
```

Here is the code for lrRocAucTest

```
def execute(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    clf = Pipeline([
        # ('feature_selection', SelectKBest(f_classif, k=9)),
        ('classifier', LogisticRegression(C=0.1))
    ])
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    predictions = clf.predict(X_test)

    try:
        accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test.values.ravel(), predictions)
    except AttributeError:
        accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)

    cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions)
    recall = (cnf_matrix[1, 1] / (cnf_matrix[1, 0] + cnf_matrix[1, 1]))


    y_prediction = clf.decision_function(X_test)

    try:
        fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test.values.ravel(), y_prediction)
    except AttributeError:
        fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, y_prediction)
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)

    values = {'fpr': fpr, 'tpr': tpr, 'roc_auc': roc_auc,
              'accuracy': accuracy, 'cnf_mtx': cnf_matrix, 'recall': recall}
    return values
```

The above code executes the Logistic Regression classifier and returns some values. I'm interested in the fpr and tpr. These are arrays in the form of `[1, 2, 3,..., n]` and fpr and tpr will be the same length.

What I what to do is to get `all_fpr` which is a list of arrays and the average of all them in order to produce one single array. I'll give an example to make things clear. Lets say we have 3 array [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [8.0, 9.0, 10.0], [14.0, 15.0, 16.0]. The resulting single array would be [7.7, 8.7, 9.7].

Is there a way to run a classifier multiple times in scikit-learn? Or will I have to write the logic myself?

Comment: Don't say 'run a classifier', that could mean either 'train' or 'predict'. You meant 'train'. Also, you haven't shown the code that instantiates `lrRocAucTest`, it presumably wraps your LR classifier that takes a random seed `random_state`. For determinism and reproducibility, you probably want to set that seed to one of a set of known values on each run.

Comment: I've added the code for `lrRocAucTest`